# How to load 2 xml files via Jquery?

Tags: jquery, xml

I have got 2 xml files(data.xml and images.xml) to load into a div structure like:

```
<div class="listing">
    <div class="listing-image"></div>
    <div class="listing-data"></div>
</div>
```

How can I load them together? here is data.xml

```
<dealer id="123">
    <name>Lily's Trucks</name>
</div>
<dealer id="456">
    <name>Ali's Trucks</name>
</div>
<dealer id="789">
    <name>May's Trucks</name>
</div>
```

and images.xml

```
<images>
    <image source="/image1.jpg" id="123"/>
    <image source="/image2.jpg" id="456"/>
    <image source="/image3.jpg" id="789"/>
</images>
```

The output should be:

```
<div class="listing">
    <div class="listing-image"><img src="/image1.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="listing-data">Name: Lily's Trucks</div>
</div>
<div class="listing">
    <div class="listing-image"><img src="/image2.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="listing-data">Name: Ali's Trucks</div>
</div>
<div class="listing">
    <div class="listing-image"><img src="/image3.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="listing-data">Name: May's Trucks</div>
</div>
```

Cheers.

Comment: Basic overview is you'll need to write javascript code to load the XML into a string, pass in to [parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), and then generate the HTML based upon the data in the object that parseXML gave you . . .

Answer (score 0):

use jquery.load()

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.listing-image').load('http://images.xml');
        $('.listing-data').load('http://data.xml');
    });
</script>


<div class="listing">
    <div class="listing-image"></div>
    <div class="listing-data"></div>
</div>
```